# C# XDocument needs to be parsed to XML again

Tags: c#, xml

I have a Xdocument that is populated as follows:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
```

This gives me an XDocument that looks as follows:

```
<GetReportAsXMLString>
     <report>
        <reportItem Count ="562..................
</GetReportAsXMLStringResult>
```

Anything between the   tag is all just a giant string(Black). How would I get this portion of the document to format as XML? The  tag is also part of the string. I just don't know how to make this show it as not XML.

Thanks

Comment: We're gonna need more info about what's under the <report> element...

Comment: Yes...between the <report> and </report> it is all XML it is just formatted as a string. What I am trying to do is say IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xDoc.Element("ReportItem"); to get the elements under Report Item but it doesnt recognize it as XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say from your description, but it looks like you'll need to first parse the response stream (valid xml), which contains another xml document (as a string). You'll need to extract the string from the 'outer' xml document and parse it into a new one:

psuedocode:

```
XDocument outer = response.GetResponseStream();
String innerXml = outer.Element("report").Value;
XDocument inner = XDocument.Parse(innerXml);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this XML content :

```
<GetReportAsXMLString>
  <report>
    <reportItem Count =\"562\"/>
    <reportItem Count =\"562\"/>
  </report>
</GetReportAsXMLString>
```

and you want to extract only the "reportItem" nodes?

If so you can do this:

```
string xml = "<GetReportAsXMLString><report><reportItem Count =\"562\"/><reportItem Count =\"562\"/></report></GetReportAsXMLString>";
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
IEnumerable<XElement> elList = xDoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("report")).Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("reportItem"));
```